# Laravel Eloquent firstOrFail returns all records in table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve a row in my eloquent model. What I want to do is first search to see if it exists or throw an exception. In the Laravel docs, it says I can use `firstOrFail` or `findOrFail`. The eloquent query is as follows:

`Game::where('game', 'game-name')->firstOrFail()->remember(60)->get()`

This works for finding the record and throwing an exception if not found however it returns all rows as a result. What I would like to do is just return the row that I've searched for. I am not indexing by primary key in this example so findOrFail doesn't work.

If I replace `->get()` with `->first()` all it does is return the first row in the table. It ignores the `::where()`.

**EDIT:** When I removed `->get()` and `->remember()` it returned the desired row however I still would like to cache the query but when I use `->remember()` and print_r on the result, the entire eloquent model is dumped.

**EDIT2:** All is resolved. I always confuse the place of `->remember()`. The correct way to do this is:

`Game::where('game', 'game-name')->remember(60)->firstOrFail()`

Comment: It's not remember, it's `first` `firstOrFail` `get` `find` etc that you have to take care of. All of them execute the query and return `collection`/`model`/`null` (or `array`) so you in fact did run the query you wanted, then called `remember` and ran another query with `get`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All is resolved. 
I always confuse the place of `->remember()`.
The correct way to do this is:

```
Game::where('game', 'game-name')->remember(60)->firstOrFail()
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong result seems to be cached, avoid using remember until you have the right query.
If you use *get* it will return a Collection instance.
*findOrFail* expect an id as the first parameter.
Get the first result from your query with *first* and then check if it is empty to throw an Exception

```
Game::where('game', 'game-name')->first();
```

Comment: please post an answer with the solution you found, and accept your own answer. It will help others.